# Pandas column indexing differ in iloc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

what is the difference between the two below code

```
my_data.iloc[:,2:3]
```

&

```
my_data.iloc[:,2]
```

why the result differ eventhough it seems same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One output `DataFrame` another one is return `Series`

```
type(df.iloc[2:3])
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
type(df.iloc[2])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```